# Login-AzureRmAccount : -Credential parameter can only be used with Organization ID credentials

Tags: azure

While logging into the Azure account through powershell, I am getting the error - 
Login-AzureRmAccount : -Credential parameter can only be used with Organization ID credentials. 
I need to understand when this error comes?

`````
    [string]$TenantID,
    [string]$ApplicationID,
    [string]$SecretKey,
    [string]$ProcessInstanceID,
                [string]$Endpoint
)

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $SecretKey -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ApplicationID, $securePassword)
$profilePath = "D:\" + $ProcessInstanceID + "_azureProfile.json"

Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process

$azureok = $null
while ($azureok -eq $null) {
    if($Endpoint -match "china"){
    Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantID -Credential $cred -Environment AzureChinaCloud -ea silentlycontinue -wa silentlycontinue -ev errorvar | out-null
    }
    else{
    Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantID -Credential $cred -ea silentlycontinue -wa silentlycontinue -ev errorvar | out-null 
    }
    if ($errorvar.exception -ne $null) {
        if ($errorvar.exception.message -eq "An error occurred while sending the request.") {
            Start-sleep -s 10
            $error.clear()
        } else {
            break
        }
    } else {
        $azureok = $true
    }
}

Save-AzureRmContext -Path $profilePath ````


Error message - 
Login-AzureRmAccount : -Credential parameter can only be used with Organization ID credentials.
`````

Comment: What "Credential parameters" are you using in your powershell script ? can you post your script please ? (minus authentication details of course).

Comment: Could you please have a try to use -Name <username>@<e-mail-suffix>.onmicrosoft.com for your credential parameter.

Comment: @scott_lotus In description

Comment: I've been using this for ages: `$cred = [pscredential]::new($va1,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $va2 -AsPlainText -Force)); Add-AzAccount -TenantId $env:AZURE_TENANT_ID -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred`. works fine